# Visual Studio 2019 Will Not Debug Azure Function V2

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I am having trouble debugging a Azure Function App. I have created the Function App using the default HTTP Trigger template in VS2019. The console windows opens and I can get a 200 OK response back using Postman,however,

1. No breakpoints are being hit.
2. The console will not shutdown when I stop debugging.
3. No modules are being loaded.

It is as if I have used Ctrl F5 to run wothout degugging.
I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution.
I started a new project and build a new function app but still no good.

Is there a debug setting that is set incorrectly?

Comment: I know that it is painful, but I think you should reinstall (Or repair) your VS installation. This sounds like a machine related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very similar to a known issue with the Debug option to allow closing the console window when stopping.
Have a look here, maybe there's something that can help you?

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/665957/azure-functions-projects-never-hit-breakpoints-whe.html

Comment: Yes i un-checked the Automatically close the console window and debugging came back. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the latest Azure Functions Tools and that you've followed the steps outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs